# jhipster bookstore tutorial - Only display the footer view at runtime

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, jhipster

I'm trying to start using hipster. I've completed the installation and tried to recreate the same bookstore app like in the demo video.
Everything went well (installation, app creation, app startup, DB schema creation) but when I access the application in the browser, I only the text "This is your footer". I don't have the header and the body like in the demo. There is no error in the console. I assume something is wrong with AngularJS but I don't know what.

I'm on Mac OS 10.10
JDK 1.8._45
eclipse Luna (I've successfully imported the generated hipster project as a Maven project)

If you have any suggestion on where to investigate. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the console for javascript errors.

Comment: Good idea. Getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable : Angular

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the root cause was that the bower components were not properly installed.
To resolve the issue, I've done:

- sudo xcodebuild -license  (without agreeing with the license, it was
  preventing bower to complete)
- sudo bower install --allow-root (to download all the components)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Google Chrome. Fixed by clearing cache and cookie.
Maybe, it`s help you too.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used a postgresql database. I changed the user password in both application-dev.xml and application-prod.xml and also on the database.

alter user myuser password 'mypassword' ;

then restarted the app with command mvn sprint-boot:run

then it worked